# Generic and clean way to execute a method only after a certain period of time

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks

Let's say every `PeriState` method is called a 100 time per second. I'd like to execute `PeriState_A` method only once a day after the first occurrence, and `PeriState_B` once a hour after the first occurrence and so on.
What is the cleanest, generic way to do this. I don't necessarily need coding example. A hint or a pattern name might help as well.
So my goal here is to keep the code clean as possible and source the time management in a separate file.

```
PeriState_A
01/01/2022 10:00 -> Write log.
01/01/2022 11:00 -> Ignore
01/01/2022 22:00 -> Ignore
02/01/2022 09:50 -> Ignore
02/01/2022 10:10 -> Write log.
```

See code below.

```
private DateTime periStateA_called;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var program = new Program();
    program.Startup();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private void Startup()
{
    var appleTimer = new Timer(1000);
    var bananaTimer = new Timer(1500);
    var cranberriesTimer = new Timer(2000);
    appleTimer.Elapsed += PeriState_A;
    appleTimer.Interval = 1000;
    appleTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void PeriState_A(object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (periStateA_called < DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromHours(24)) {
        Console.WriteLine("PeriState_A");
        periStateA_called = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

private static void PeriState_B(object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PeriState_B");
}

private static void PeriState_C(object? source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("PeriState_C");
}
```

Comment: What about using 3rd party open source libraries such as hangfire.io ?

Comment: There is a lot of scheduler libs accesible via nuget like  Quartz, hangfire, ..., or you can make your own scheduler using Timer

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use Windows' scheduled tasks. You can call the function as the initial parameter.

Comment: Windows scheduled Task is not an option, because the `PeriState_A` method is called a couple of times in the code and I have to implement it in the code.

Comment: Does it require a specific time of day or does it have to run once a day from the moment the program runs?

Comment: I'd like to be able to configure it in the code. Some Methods should only trigger at earliest after the fist occurrence in one hour, others once a day after the first occurrence but only if the method is called. Not fixed after one hour or one day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private DateTime EventAPrevRun = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
private DateTime EventBPrevRun = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); 
//this should run only one hour 
public void EventA()
{
    if(EventAPrevRun < DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
{
    EventAPrevRun = DateTime.Now;
    //Do stuff
}

}
//this should run only one day
public void EventB()
{
   if(EventBPrevRun < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
   {
    EventBPrevRun = DateTime.Now;
    //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Is here a generic and a clean way to do this? I'd like to separate time management in a specific file without writing if statements.

Comment: follow @J.Salas comment.